# Как скопировать содержимое одного массива в другой, если они разных размерностей?

Tags: c++, c, динамические-массивы

Мне необходимо из определённого текстового файла создать новый, обрезав его содержимое так, что бы количество символов в файле было кратно 20.

Лишние символы записать в ещё один текстовый файл.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<algorithm>

int main()
{
    char *f_content; //Массив для хранения содержимого исходного файла
    char *f_content_cpy; //Массив для хранения обрезанной копии

    std::ifstream fin("afile.txt"); //Открываем исходный файл и считаем 
                                    // количество символов
    char *character;
    int count = 0;
    while (fin >> character) ++count;
    delete character;

    int round = ((count + 2)/20) * 20; //Подсчитываем максимально близкое к count число кратное 20

    f_content = new char[count];
    fin >> f_content; // Заполняем массив содержимым исходного файла
    fin.close();

    f_content_cpy = new char[round];
    std::copy_n(f_content, round, f_content_cpy);

    for (int i = 0; i < round; i++) // Все символы в массиве кроме тех, что идут после индекса round приравниваем к 'i'
    {
        f_content[i] = 'i';
    }

    std::ofstream fout("temp_nums.txt", std::ios_base::app), // temp_nums.txt - Для хранения лишних символов
                  fout_("new_afile.txt");

    fout_ << f_content_cpy; //Записываем обработанные данные в новый файл
    fout_.close();
    delete [] f_content_cpy;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (f_content[i] != 'i')
        {
            fout << f_content[i];
        }
    }

    fout.close();
    delete [] f_content;
}
```

На выходе файл "new_afile.txt" оказывается пустым, а в "temp_nums.txt" записываются 4 (Именно на столько символов сокращается файл) пробела.

Я думаю что проблема в записи данных из одного массива в другой.

Помимо std::copy_n() я так же пробовал записать данные через for с количеством итераций round, что бы в f_content_cpy записались только символы до индекса round из f_content, но результат был тот же.

Comment: Если бы вы попробовали отладить свою программу, то обнаружили бы, что *"fin >> f_content; // Заполняем массив содержимым исходного файла"* на самом деле этого не делает. Ну и вообще никакие массивы никуда копировать в этом задании не нужно.

Comment: И если вы уже работаете со стандартными алгоритмами, то зачем вам заморачиваться с массивами? Ведь кроме стандартных алгоритмов есть еще и стандартные контейнеры...

Comment: Не мешайте си и с++. Ввод и вывод с++ через >> и << не умеет работать с сишными стоками, и указателями. Работают с ними как с числами. Используйте контейнеры `std::string`. `fin >> character` тоже взорвётся. Точнее character будет указывать на мусор и `delete character` упадёт.

Comment: Лишние файлы записать в ещё один текстовый файл... И откуда в файле лишные файлы? Может лишные симолы?...

Comment: В первом же цикле при подсчёте символов вы считываете *строку* (`fin >> character`) с указателем на мусор памяти. Всё сразу падает. Нужно использовать функцию `read`.

Comment: Узнайте размер файла ([fstat()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)) и если он уже не кратен 20, то  вычислите его новый размер, перепишите хвост (от 1 до 19 байт) в новый файл   и наконец, обрежьте исходный файл ([ftruncate()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftruncate))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет стандартного способа обрезания открытого файла с помощью fstream.
Поэтому, не считая многочисленных других ошибок, ваш код абсолютно не годится, а я предложу такой пример:

```
void rewrite( std::ofstream& fout)
{   
    std::fstream fin("afile.txt");        
    using R = std::istream_iterator<char>;
    using W = std::ostream_iterator<char>;
    std::vector<char> v;
    std::copy(R(fin), R(), std::back_inserter(v));
    const size_t size = v.size();
    if (size > 20) {
        size_t sz = size - size % 20;
        if (sz != size) {           
            std::copy(v.begin() + sz, v.end(), W(fout));
            remove("afile.txt");
            std::copy_n(v.begin(), sz, W(fin));
        }
    }   
}

int main() { 
    std::ofstream fout("temp_nums.txt");
    rewrite(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

Вы от себя добаьте проверку на открытий файлов. И, конечно закрывйте их вовремя

Comment: И что будет с компом для файла в пару гигов?

Comment: @avp, уместный вопрос, но это лишь пример, для демонстрации. Конечно лучше по строкам пройтись или  считать обьем файла,  но, так как ТС  пытался считывать посимвольно, я  показал пример такой же

Comment: В таких задачах надо использовать специфические средства ОС (обычно есть их системонезависимые POSIX реализации) типа `fstat`, `open`, `read`, `write`, `ftruncate` ... (а язык, вызывающий их, может быть любой, в т.ч. и С++)

Comment: @avp, ну раз вы знаете, что мешает вам  показать это в виде ответа? Не хотите помогать?

Comment: Устыдили. Написал программку в ответ

Comment: Зато она может быть полезной. Я не  пишу программы, обрабатывающие файлы, но кому то точно может помочь...

Comment: Правда, судя  по заголовку вопроса, вряд ли кто-то, кому она может помочь ее увидит -)

Comment: @avp, лично для меня это была хорошая информация,  поэтому, лично от меня,  спасибо  вы уже получили в виде  плюса на вашем ответе

Answer (score 1):

Возможный POSIX вариант.

Переписывает только "хвост", используя буфер разумного размера, урезает исходный файл по месту.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFSIZE (64 * 1024)

off_t
rnd_file (const char *srcf, const char *tailf, size_t rem)
{
  if (!rem)
    return -EINVAL;
  struct stat s;
  if (stat(srcf, &s))
    return -errno;
  size_t t_size = s.st_size % rem;
  if ((size_t)s.st_size < rem || t_size == 0)
    return -EDOM; // nothing to do

  size_t newsz = s.st_size - t_size;
  int rc = 0,
    in = open(srcf, O_RDWR);
  if (in == -1)
    return -errno;
  int out = creat(tailf, 0666 /* (rw-rw-rw) & ~umask) */);
  if (out == -1)
    return rc = -errno, close(out), rc;

  char buf[BUFSIZE];
  if (lseek(in, newsz, SEEK_SET) == -1)
    return rc = -errno, close(in), close(out), rc;

  while (t_size) {
    int l, rl = t_size < BUFSIZE ? t_size : BUFSIZE;
    if ((l = read(in, buf, rl)) != rl ||
        write(out, buf, l) != l)
      return rc = -errno, close(in), close(out), rc;
    t_size -= l;
  }

  if (ftruncate(in, newsz) || close(in) || close(out))
    return -errno;

  return newsz;
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac != 4)
    exit((printf("Usage: %s in-file tail-fail MULTIPLE\n", av[0]), 2));

  off_t res = rnd_file(av[1], av[2], atoi(av[3]));
  if (res < 0)
    exit((perror("rnd_file"), 1));
  printf("newsize: %zu\n", (size_t)res);

  return 0;
}
```

Код компилируется как `gcc`, так и `g++`.
При компиляции с `-std=c99` (или `c11`) можно добавить `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500`, чтобы избавиться от сообщения:
`warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ftruncate’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`